# increasing the sample size of data within watson studio

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-studio

When I added a dataset compiled in a .csv to the Watson studio, it limits the data to be limited to first 1000 rows. My .csv file contains a total of 7000 rows of data. How to increase the sample size to become more than 1000 rows in the IBM Watson studio?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Many unfamiliar with the tool and those very technical would have the same question. I certainly did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample size is fixed to 1000 rows for data refinery in watson studio.

The sample is meant to be use to get preview of your dataset and not meant to show full dataset.
When you run the actual data refinery job, it will run it over the full dataset and will apply the steps you have defined in refinery job.

If you are concerned about skews in your dataset, you should be using the profiling functionality to profile columns and see the skews.